# Split varchar2 variable based on vertical line delimiter

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have following plsql code

```
DECLARE
   v_personal_info VARCHAR2(100);
   v_name VARCHAR2(100);
   v_signature VARCHAR2(100);
   CURSOR c_personal_info
   IS
     select personal_info from users where name is not null;
BEGIN
  FOR lr_row IN c_personal_info
  LOOP
    v_personal_info := lr_row.personal_info;
    -- Need to split v_personal_info based on |
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Typical values of `v_personal_info` will look like `'Aniket Thakur | athakur'` and I need to split this to different variables like

```
v_name := 'Aniket Thakur'
v_signature := 'athakur'
```

How should I do that. Is there any in built function that does a split based on predefined delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the functions [INSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions089.htm#SQLRF00651) to locate the poition of '|' in the string and [SUBSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions196.htm#SQLRF06114) to retrieve the relevant part of the string.

So

```
select  
    SUBSTR(personal_info, 1, INSTR(personal_info, '|') - 1),
    SUBSTR(personal_info,INSTR(personal_info, '|') +1 )
from users
```

will returrn two columns with the appropriate parts of personal_info.

Answer (score 0):

I usex simple `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` methods.

```
DECLARE
   v_personal_info VARCHAR2(100);
   v_name VARCHAR2(100);
   v_signature VARCHAR2(100);
   delimitIndex number;
   CURSOR c_personal_info
   IS
     select personal_info from users where name is not null;
BEGIN
  FOR lr_row IN c_personal_info
  LOOP
    v_personal_info := lr_row.personal_info;
    delimitIndex := INSTR(v_personal_info, '|');
    if delimitIndex != 0 then
        v_name := SUBSTR(v_personal_info, 1, delimitIndex - 1);
        v_signature := SUBSTR(v_personal_info, delimitIndex+1, LENGTH(v_personal_info)-delimitIndex);
    END if;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare
 v_texto VARCHAR2(100) :='AAAA|BBB|DDDD';
BEGIN
 while INSTR(v_texto,'|')>0 LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line( SUBSTR(v_texto, 1, INSTR(v_texto, '|') - 1) );
  v_texto:= SUBSTR(v_texto, INSTR(v_texto, '|')+1, LENGTH(v_texto)-INSTR(v_texto, '|'));
 END LOOP;
dbms_output.put_line('------');
 v_texto:= SUBSTR(v_texto, INSTR(v_texto, '|')+1, LENGTH(v_texto)-INSTR(v_texto, '|'));
   dbms_output.put_line(v_texto);
END;
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining it